# I am using glob module of python and getting an empty list in return. what should i do?

Tags: python, glob

```
def get_quote(self,feel):
    feel=feel.lower()
    availabel_feelings =  glob.glob("quotes\*txt")
    print(availabel_feelings)

    availabel_feelings=[Path(filename).stem for filename in availabel_feelings]
    if feel in availabel_feelings:
        with open(f"quotes/{feel}.txt" ) as file:
            # print(file.read())
            quotes=file.readlines()
        self.ids.quote.txt=random.choice(quotes) 
    else:
        self.ids.quote.txt="try another feeling"
```

Comment: Why are you escaping the `*`? You are trying to match the literal file name `quote*txt`, not file names that begin with `quote` and end with `txt`.

Comment: Judging from the `open(f"quotes/{feel}.txt" )` I think the \ is a mistake and should be a `/`. I don't think the `*` is being intentionally escaped.

Answer (score 0):

try removing the `\` from the pathname pattern

```py
availabel_feelings =  glob.glob("quotes*.txt")
```

I don't think you want to scape the `*` character here

Comment: if you want to look inside folders use `recursive=True`